# How can I collect two options each with multiple arguments in Python's argparse module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse, docopt

I want to parse two long command line options - a list of files and a command like so:

```
python example.py file1 file2 -- echo hello world
```

With a result of:

```
>>> args.filenames
["file1", "file2"]
>>> args.command
["echo", "hello", "world"]
```

Is this possible in argparse or any other python CLI library (such as docopt)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In argparse, the `--` means, treat everything that follows as positional strings.  But all strings in your sample look like that, so the `--` does nothing.  So the remaining question is, how is argparse suppose to to allocate the 5 strings to 2 arguments.  `nargs=2`, and `narg='*'` would do the trick if you always want 2 'files'.  `+` and `REMAINDER` (`...`) would also work for the 2nd.

What won't work is `*` followed by `*`.  That would be akin to a RegEx pattern of `'(a*)(a*)'`.  In fact argparse uses RegEx pattern matching to allocate strings to positional arguments.  Creating the 2 arguments, and trying various `nargs` values can be instructive.

Another option is to replace the `--` with an optionals argument, e.g. `-c` with a `nargs='*'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', nargs='*')
>>> parser.add_argument('--bar', nargs='*')
>>> parser.parse_args('--foo x y --bar 1 2'.split())
Namespace(bar=['1', '2'], foo=['x', 'y'])
```

Also for your files argument you can also use `type=argparse.FileType('w')` or `type=argparse.FileType('r')` and it will create file objects for you when parsing the input